# Rename image when uploading in WordPress via Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to import some products to WooCommerce via Rest API: `https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product`

I use this code to transfer products:

```
<?php
    $data = [
        'name' => 'Premium Quality',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'regular_price' => '21.99',
        'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
        'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
        'categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 9
            ],
            [
                'id' => 14
            ]
        ],
        'images' => [
            [
                'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
            ],
        ]
    ];
    
    print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
    ?>
```

After transferring the product, the name of the image remains unchanged: `T_2_front.jpg`

I want the image name to be changed to a random number. like this: `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads//1919.jpg`

**How do I change the name of the image when uploading?**

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties) says in **Product - Images properties**, you can pass the image name in the request; your code can be like this:

```php
<?php
$data = [
    'name' => 'Premium Quality',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '21.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg',
            'name' => uniqid()
        ],
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
?>
```

You can use `uniqid` to generate a unique id or other methods like `rand` and `random_int`.

Also, you can set `alt` for the image if you want.

**Updated:**

To change the URL you can use the `wp_handle_sideload_prefilter` action like this:

```php
add_action('wp_handle_sideload_prefilter', function ($file) {

    $explodedFilename = explode('.', $file['name']);
    $file['name'] = uniqid() . '.' . end($explodedFilename);
    return $file;

});
```

As the last version of Woocommerce, this action will call in `wp-admin/includes/file.php:803`, and we can change the name.

Comment: It cannot rename the image in the link

Comment: This code needs to run in WordPress, I only have access via api. So this code cannot solve the problem

Comment: @seyedrezabazyar unfortunately, I think this can not be done from the rest side.
If you find a way, please share it.